# Cannot create new Activerecord with belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am a beginner with Ruby on Rails and I am trying to create a seed.rb file to populate my database.

However I am having problems creating a new `Request` record.

This is my seed file:

```
if Rails.env == "development" || Rails.env == "test"

  avaya = Company.create!(name: "Avaya")
  microsoft = Company.create!(name: "Microsoft")
  bradesco = Company.create!(name: "Bradesco")

  customer = Customer.create!(name: "Leon Schmidt", email: "leon.schmidt@avaya.com", company_id: avaya.id)
  Customer.create!(name: "Teri Wright", email: "teri.wright@avaya.com", company_id: avaya.id)
  Customer.create!(name: "Jasmine Bush", email: "jasmine.bush@microsoft.com", company_id: microsoft.id)
  Customer.create!(name: "Jake Blair", email: "jake.blair@bradesco.com.br", company_id: bradesco.id)

  rate = Rate.create!(rate: 0.0165, days: 10, default_rate: true)

  Request.create!(title_value: 1500, term: 28, monthly_revenue: 75000, receivable_value: 1425.75, rate_id: rate.id, customer_id: customer.id)

elsif Rails.env == "production"

  Rate.create(rate: 0.0165, days: 10, default_rate: true)

end
```

Whenever I run rake db:reset to repopulate the development database I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Customers must exist
c:/Desenvolvimento/Coding Tests/FactoringRateCalculator/db/seeds.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:reset => db:setup => db:seed
```

Please note that the line 23 is: `Request.create!(title_value: 1500, term: 28, monthly_revenue: 75000, receivable_value: 1425.75, rate_id: rate.id, customer_id: customer.id)`

My models are below:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :requests

  validates_associated :requests
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, email: true
end

class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customers, required: true
  belongs_to :rate, required: true

  validates :term, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 10 }
  validates :title_value, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 500 }
  validates :monthly_revenue, :receivable_value, presence: true, numericality: true
end

class Rate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :requests
  validates_associated :requests

  validates :rate, numericality: true, presence: true
  validates :days, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 10 }, presence: true
  validates :rate, :days, :default_rate, presence: true
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customers

  validates_associated :customers
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

I am using Ruby 2.3 and Rails 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `required` validation is specified with the plural version of your model:

```
belongs_to :customers, required: true
```

Try using the singular way:

```
belongs_to :customer, required: true
```

That's why the error says *"Customers"*: `"ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Customers must exist"`, because your seeds have been made following the relationship you specify.

Comment: Yes, you were right! I changed the `Customers` to `Customer` and it worked. Thanks for the help!